# nbformat error trying to open jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to install Jupyter Notebook in macOS Mojave.

I have tryied with Anaconda but although anaconda3 is apparently well installed, with the correct path in my bash, I get:

```
$ jupyter notebook
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

I have also tried with

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`python3 -m pip install jupyter`

but after I try to open `jupyter notebook` I get this error:

```
$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielavargasrobles/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/danielavargasrobles/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "/Users/danielavargasrobles/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbformat'
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did you installed jupyter inside your envirnoment ?
I had a similar issue, jupyter was launching because installed outside venv but not installed inside your envirnoment it will lead to nbformat issue.

```
conda activate your_env
conda install jupyter
```

should do the trick.